How does $\int_{C} F \cdot dr = \int_{C} f(x,y) ds$
I figured out how $\int_{C} P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = \int_{C} F \cdot dr$ because it's mainly derivatives and letting multiple components become a single vector.
Right now, I'm working with the former expression, but I'm unsure the relatinoship between $P$ and $Q$ (used in $\int_{C} P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy$) and $f$ (that is used in $\int_{C} f(x,y) ds$.
All of them should be equivalent but I'm not sure what the substitution would be.
edit: I want to use the Pythagorean theorem for the arc length, and then let $f(x,y) = P \frac{dx}{ds} + Q\frac{dy}{dx}$ or something like that? This way, the function shows how much contribution from the vector there is at a particular point?

Do you know that $ds$ is an arc length element? That could be a start.

I know the idea that $ds$ is a small arc element and $f(x,y)$ is the value of the function, and the integral adds these up (usually with a fence analogy). I also know the vector version is adding up the tangential components of the vector field (usually with a work analogy). But rather than approach things two different ways, I want to transform one into the other.

You derived the correct relations.

Briefly, $\int_C F\cdot dr = \int_C F\cdot T\,ds$, where $T$ is the unit tangent vector to $C$.
You cannot in general go the other way, however. Note that a $ds$ integral stays the same when you reverse the curve, whereas the work line integral changes sign.

Thanks. So, from what I understand, my initial question is incorrect. That is, although $\int_C} F \cdot dr$ and $\int_{C} f(x,y)ds$ are both line integrals, there's not a general relationship between them because they're designed differently from the start.
